Adding a counter for the position of a record in a R dataframe in a "for" loop
I have some code that runs a sports league table standings simulation, using a "for" loop in R. For each iteration of the loop, a table of standings (i.e. a dataframe) df is produced like this:
       Team       Points 
1   Arsenal         12     
2   Chelsea         11     
3   Liverpool       9    
4   Newcastle       9     
5   Man U           7     
6   Fulham          6  

Suppose I run n simulations (i.e. something like for(i in 1:n) {...} I would like to count the number of times a certain team finishes in top 3 position. For instance I want to count Chelsea. How can I add this feature?  Obviously I need to add a counter that starts at 0 and increments by 1 every time Chelsea is in top 3 of the table for that respective loop iteration. But how?

Would a tie for 3rd (based on Points alone) count?

This is how to add a counter to a for loop:
counter <- 0
for(i in 1:10){
  counter <- counter + 1
  print(counter)
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10

Merely printing the counter object outside of the loop tells you the total count:
print(counter)

10

Using a while loop:
counter <- 0
while(counter < 10){
  counter <- counter + 1
}

print(counter) 

10

Hope it helps!

For your example, you may implement the counter for "Chelsea" like below
ChelseaCounter4Top3 <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
    idx <- which(df$Team == "Chelsea")
    if (idx <= 3) {
        ChelseaCounter4Top3 <- ChelseaCounter4Top3 + 1
    }
}

